# What is Space in Physics?

Tags: spacetime, vacuum, space, aether

Is space a physical ***thing*** like matter? Is it a *concrete thing* or just an *abstract concept*?

Comment: It is "physical", but not a physical thing like matter or any other substance. Space is a region where matter can reside. I wouldn't call it abstract since it clearly exists in reality.

Comment: It all depends on what you are calling "physical", "concrete" and "abstract". As stated, it is more of a philosophical question than a physics-related one.

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux There is a tendency among physicists to label as "philosophical" every question not directly amenable to formulae. I think it is a mistake. Without an idea about the entities appearing in theory, it is hard to be sure what we are speaking about. When, in GR, we speak about the geometry of space-time, we must have some idea about what space-time is to make contact with experiments. I think the answer to the present question can be given relying on Physics. It is probable that there is no consensus among physicists about the right answer. But that is a fact of (scientific) life

Comment: @GiorgioP You are certainly right.

Comment: What is the distance between these two letters :  **A**                 **B**   . To answer it you need a coordinate system which can be anything you decide, whether with mathamtics of general relativity or the width of your fingers.

Comment: Voted to reopen. This question is *not* opinion-based. It can be given a completely objective answer within the context of general relativity, for example.

Comment: The final frontier.

Comment: I think there's a case to be made for a phenomenon of space which is distorted from the objective measurement of it.  I learned (long, long ago) that there was no "there" within the event horizon of a black hole, but it still has a diameter.  (I'd argue that things that fall into black holes don't instantly teleport to a "singularity," but asymptotically approach the event horizon while infinitely free-falling through a highly distorted phenomenon space.  One day I might figure out how to make that a decent question.

Comment: What is the difference between "a concrete thing" and "an abstract concept"?

Comment: Next logical question: "Is time a physical thing?" And by the GR concept of spacetime, I believe the two questions must have the same answer (whatever that is).

Comment: @Ajad If space is just an abstract concept to you,- try to fit yourself into $1~cm^3$ of volume :-D

Comment: If you ask Physics what space is, as opposed to matter, you'll have to face what Physics has to say about matter.

Answer (score 20):

Space in general relativity (the physics theory most interested in its properties) is usually treated as an aspect of the "spacetime [manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold)": a 3+1 dimensional set of points ("events") that locally have relations that makes it possible to speak of neighbourhoods, distances and angles (a "metric topological space").

This manifold is more like a thing than an abstraction in general relativity. Its shape is determined by the field equations, phenomena like matter fields are described as functions of the spacetime points (i.e. "living on" the manifold).

Note that not all physical theories make space into a thing like this. For example, one can formulate Newtonian mechanics and special relativity in terms of mutual distances between objects and treat the intervening space as a mere abstraction. However, field theories generally care about every single point of space, making it the backdrop on which they interact.

Comment: I love your first paragraph.  It gets at the *peculiarity* of the fact that we can speak to many truths at once with abstract language.  Even more peculiar is that we do it so intuitively that we often don't realize we're doing it.  We are completely comfortable with "every odd number is followed by an even number" without first testing out the infinite series of statements: 1+1=2, 3+1=4, 5+1=6...  Sure, we might test the first two or three to make sure it makes sense, but then we accept the rest on blind faith!  Numbers are powerful things!

Comment: @CortAmmon and Anders, you guys are great! -NN

Comment: @CortAmmon blind faith...? Just because you can't "test" every number doesn't mean you can't prove a trivial statement like that. The act of defining odd and even numbers makes this a trivial proof. The same is true on a larger scale for topology in the first paragraph. Mathematicians do not proof things in the same way as science; we make our definitions and reason through the consequences. We don't run experiments to try and falsify a nulhypothesis. Our knowledge that "every odd follows an even" isn't because we tested it a bunch!

Comment: @CortAmmon that statement is trivially provable by undergraduates in an introductory proofs class.

Comment: @Eric I agree, and that's what makes it so marvelous.  Maybe it's the constructivists rubbing off on me, but I find it beautiful that I can make powerful statements about numbers that not only have I not written yet, but which have not been written by a human in all history.  Perhaps my example with odds and evens is too simple.  I always love going around gawking at the things everyone else takes for granted.  But at a more advanced level, consider stability in controls theory.  When an engineer is asked "will your plane fly?" and they answer "yes," it is in part due to...

Comment: ... a stability analysis done on the control systems which shows that it wont lose control.  Such an analysis is based on perturbations and, somehow, we can use the abstract language of math to show that a perturbation that we've never seen before and bounded only with a few numbers (e.g. frequencies and magnitude) to develop a certainty that the plane will not go unstable on *your* flight, while your life is on the line.  It really is marvelous, and peculiar.

Comment: @AAM111 You are right.  It is provable, as long as you accept the second order logic axiom of induction.  Isn't that an amazing little axiom?  Sure, we can build mathematical systems on any axioms we like, but I find it astonishing how effective mathematics is at making statements about our world using that axiom (and the other Peano arithmetic axioms) that turn out to be true.

Comment: @CortAmmon you do not need induction to prove "every odd number follows an even one"... I think your wonder at the mundanity needs a little fine-tuning. Your comments are giving the wrong impression about mathematics, physics, and engineering

Comment: @eric well we are all entitled to our opinion on what the right and wrong impressions look like

Comment: @CortAmmon actually, we’re not — that’s one of the *actual* powerful & cool things about math! There are provably true/false statements in math, unlike a science. So statements about “blind faith” or “needing induction” are just false, not opinions. But this is becoming off topic. My goal was to correct your false statements in the comments in cases readers got the wrong ideas, and I’ve done that.

Answer (score 9):

In the context of general relativity, space is not a physical thing like matter or radiation. However, neither is it entirely abstract. Once you set up an inertial reference frame and a metric, then you can measure distances between locations in space. These distances have physical effects - for example, the distance between two locations determines the minimum time that it takes for information to travel from one location to another, and this minimum time is independent of the choice of reference frame. So space is concrete but immaterial.

Comment: You should explain what you mean by "physical thing". Some might consider a "physical thing" anything in the universe that can be studied by the methods of physics. Or something that can be characterized quantitatively, or something that can be interacted with. Space fulfills all of these properties (in GR).

Answer (score 6):

Your question could be a question about knowledge, how we perceive Nature and what we consider as real things, and more philosophical arguments.

Broadly speaking, in Physics as the science of Nature, following the scientific method by Galileo, as far as we can measure it in a reliable and repeatable way, a thing is a physical entity.

**In the limits of classical physics**, space is an invariant physical entity (i.e. independent from other physical quantities, and from the observer who describes the phenomenon) and we can use rulers and set squares to measure distances and angles or other more advanced instruments: we can use different instruments but we can agree on the measures and repeat them within the precision of each instruments.

Thus to be precise, we can't measure space itself but distances and **relative** position/orientation between points and objects in space.

**In Einstein's relativity**, space  must be considered along with time in space-time to be an absolute/invariant with respect to the observer/coordinates used to describe a physical process, or Nature. When the effects described by Einstein's relativity theory are relevant in a physical process, two observers (even inertial observers, in relative motion) do not agree on measurements of space distance between two events, but they do on measurements of distance between two events in **space-time**.

So space can be interpreted here as a projection of the physical entity space-time.

Answer (score 4):

I think the space is a "concrete thing" because it expands. Its physical measure is volume, I guess.

The expansion of space might be related to creation of the new matter (e.g. particle-antiparticle pairs at the event horizon of the black holes, etc.). Due to expansion of space, the positive energy of the new matter is compensated by the negative potential energy of gravitational attraction of the massive objects.

Answer (score 4):

Space is as physical as anything. You measure it with a ruler. The fundamental objects of physics are those you can measure with simple instruments (clocks, balances, force gauges, thermometers, ...). Both the abstractions of theory and the concrete measurements made with more sophisticated instruments are founded on this base.

Answer (score 3):

You assume that matter is a simple and straightforward thing to understand, and also that material things, tangibly made out of solid matter, are the most obvious paradigm of "thingness." And I agree with you, because I am also a human being that grew up on this planet, and for me too such are the primary givens of childhood experience... being most intimately connected to everyday life, they seem the easiest to understand. (Moderator: I refer to personal experience here only metonymically, of course I mean everyman not just myself.)

It is not so.

Yes, spacetime is physical, just like matter. The more you learn about it, the more mysterious *all of the above* will become. The manner in which we get an intellectual handle on any of these physical "things" (or *somethings*) necessarily involves abstraction, and we are guided by concrete experiment/experience which of course also evolves from our primary senses to highly advanced equipment.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

In physics, space is a concept that refers to the three-dimensional expanse in which all matter exists. It is often considered to be a void or emptiness, but this is not entirely accurate. Space is a physical thing, in the sense that it exists as a framework or structure within which all matter and energy exist and interact.

However, space is not a concrete thing like matter. It is not made up of particles or atoms, and it does not have a definite shape or size. Instead, space is an abstract concept that is used to describe the relationship between objects in the universe and the forces that act upon them.

In other words, space is the framework within which all physical phenomena occur. It is the "stage" upon which the events of the universe play out. While it is not a concrete thing like matter, it is a fundamental aspect of the physical universe and is essential for understanding the behavior of matter and energy.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As your question is so wonderfully open to interpretation, I'll interpret it in a philosophical or ontological way.

1. Except in very advanced parts of physics (anything with "quantum" in its name) space does have properties but is pretty clearly not a "thing" in the sense of an "object". You have the tag `aether` in your question, and space is definitely not that, by all our current theories. Space is not a bunch of very thin water or air.
2. Since space does have properties in many areas of physics, for example lengths, volumes and such - even non-constant in Einsteinian physics - it is certainly a *mathematical* object. Note that the causation goes from reality towards mathematics, not the other way round. Only because we can describe space using mathematical objects does not mean that space "is" something.
3. As of 2022, nobody knows what space *actually*, "really" is, in the sense that we know a bit about what matter is. For matter, light, and other stuff in the universe, we have a good theory (based on the 4 fundamental forces  or interactions our physics is all about these days, of which electromagnetism accounts for basically everything we can see or experience on a human level). We have nothing comparable for space itself. Yes, relativism tells us a lot about how space *behaves* when it interacts with matter or energy, but we have no idea what it *is* in the sense that we know that an atom is something which consists of a nucleus and an electron cloud and so on and so forth.
4. It seems intuitive to me (as a layperson) that there must be more to space than it just being total emptiness in which light, matter etc. flutter around, simply because of some of the advanced quantum-based effects like spontaneous creation of particles/antiparticles literally out of nothing ([Quantum Fluctuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_fluctuation), possibly proven by the [Casimir Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_effect)). Eventually, physicists working on the [Grand Unified Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Unified_Theory) might figure it out, but even then I could very well imagine that our then-new knowledge about space will be so esoteric that it will be very hard to bring down to the level of everyday people.
5. There is a great little [video on the question "Why?" by Richard Feynman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=36GT2zI8lVA) which gives a good reasoning on why even though theoretical physics might eventually figure out the formulae surrounding Space, we will be no closer to knowing what it actually is (in short: when asking why (or in this case, what) something is, any answer one can give invites more detailed follow-up questions, with no bottom). Even if that interview is rather tangentially related to this topic, it's a great background when thinking about what physical reality actually "is".